# What are the algebraic steps to get these transformed coefficients?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The literature describes how the following regression model can be written down in the standard form. However, I don't see how they obtain the coefficients in the transformed variables.

$$
\begin{gathered}
y_t\left(\frac{s_t}{\omega_1}+\frac{\left(1-s_t\right)}{\omega_2}\right)=\mu\left(\frac{s_t}{\omega_1}+\frac{\left(1-s_t\right)}{\omega_2}\right)+\varepsilon_t\left(\frac{s_t}{\omega_1}+\frac{\left(1-s_t\right)}{\omega_2}\right) \\
y_t^*=x_t^* \mu+\varepsilon_t^*,
\end{gathered}
$$
or
where $y_t^*=y_t /\left(s_t \omega_1+\left(1-s_t\right) \omega_2\right), x_t^*=1 /\left(s_t \omega_1+\left(1-s_t\right) \omega_2\right)$ and $\varepsilon_t^*=\varepsilon_t /\left(s_t \omega_1+\right.$ $\left.\left(1-s_t\right) \omega_2\right)$

Could somebody show me the algebra steps to transform the coefficients?

Comment: Update: I think the literature contains a mistake